# stop automatically changing general to dates in excel

Tags: excel-formula, formatting, excel-2007

Here is my excel file sample.
[image: Main File]

after closing and re-opening my file its automatically change in general to date formate. For that reason my file is corrupted & I loss my accounting file. It always suddenly change formula. How can I solve this error. After changing formula it looks like "error file" [image: Error File]

Now I want to know that: how can I stop automatically changing general to dates in excel.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure this will work, but I've changed old workbooks with this issue and found the problem does not persist.  Instead of leaving the formatting as general use a custom format for your numbers.

This is the custom number format I personally use because I like how it looks.

`#,##0_);(#,##0);"-"`

Hope this fixes it.